# Не собирается проект на Android

Tags: android

**app build.gradle:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.agima.mobile.cmsmagazine"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile files('src/main/libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
}
```

**project build.gradle:**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: какую ошибку дает?

Comment: да никакую, просто ничего не собирает

Comment: а как собираете-то?

Comment: а вот это apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' и вот это classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1' зачем?

Comment: ошибки выдает всегда, ищите лучше. Например, в Event Log, или Gradle Console

Comment: Уточняйте. Собираете проект или app? В файле settings.gradle для проекта инлуд для приложения есть? Что выдает `gradle build --debug`?

Answer (score 4):

Зачем вам вот эта строка

```
compile files('src/main/libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar')
```

за локальное подключение библиотеки отвечает  вот эта строка

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Удалите ее и библиотека подключится, и проект соберется.